# node is waiting for a function when I'm not using the `await` keyword

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

It was my understanding that and async function is, well, asynchronous. so it doesn't wait so caller doesn't wait for it to complete it just immediately returns a promise that will be resolved at a later time. unless you use the `await` keyword.

I'm running this code in nodejs and the results are unexpected

```js
async function foo() {
  console.log('start')
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    sum += 0.00001 * i;
  }
  console.log('finish')
  return sum;
}


function main() {
  foo()
  console.log('this should run immediately:')
}
main()
```

this is the result I get

```
start
finish
this should run immediately:
```

this is not what I expect to happen I expect the last message to print immediately and as the first message before the "start" and "finish". what am I not understanding?

Comment: _"I expect the last message to print immediately"_ - you expect the last `console.log` statement to execute _before_ `foo` function returns? `async` functions execute synchronously  _until_ the first `await` statement is encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside of `foo()` is entirely blocking and synchronous.  It won't return until the code inside it is done executing.  The addition of the keyword `async` to the function does NOT change any of that.

Many people are apparently confused by the `async` keyword.  It is useful (when combined with `await` and promise-returning asynchronous functions), but has no use at all when you don't have asynchronous code that is using promises.

The only way to keep this giant `for` loop from blocking would be to move it to a WorkerThread or a child process.  It's just synchronous and blocking and the single threaded nature of the main thread in nodejs means that when that `for` loop is running, nothing else can run (unless it's in a WorkerThread or a child process).

---

You can "defer" execution of the loop to some later time using a `setTimeout()`, but when it runs, it will still be blocking and synchronous.

Comment: This is some new insight for me. so even if I use something asynchronous like `setTimeout` for the for loop; will the `conosle.log('start')` still always happen before the `console.log('this should run immediately:')`. according to what you've said I'm assuming this is the case. the function will still run all the code synchronously until it meets something asynchronous. so the `console.log('start')` will log it, then it will run the `setTimeout` exit the function, and then the last `console.log('finish')`. then finally the `console.log('this should run immediately:')`. is this correct?

Comment: @MrBrN197 - `setTimeout()` is also non-blocking.  It just executes and schedules something to run in the future and then immediately returns.  I don't quite follow the rest of what you're asking in the comment - would have to see a code sample to know what that means.

Comment: Hi. no worries I've confirmed what I was talking about. I was simply stating that the `console.log('start')` in my code will still running before the for loop even if I defer the for loop using asynchronous code to defer the for loop.  Your answer was perfect thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
async function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log('start')
            let sum = 0;
            for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            sum += 0.00001 * i;
            }
            console.log('finish')
            resolve(sum);
    }, 0)
  })

}


function main() {
  foo()
  console.log('this should run immediately:')
}
main()
```

try like this